# Has a venomous snake ever died from a mouse bite?

Tags: snakes, mice

Long ago I read that when a mouse was put into a cobra's enclosure to feed it, the mouse ran up to the cobra, bit it, and ran into a corner.  The cobra eventually died of an infection since snakes have very weak immune systems.

Searching for that story on the internet, I found a similar story in *The Telegraph* 09 October 2008 about a mouse killing a viper in Taiwan.

https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/earth/earthnews/3353107/Mouse-bites-snake-to-death.html

This article warns that live mice & rodents fed to pet snakes could injure them.

> You may be surprised to learn that one of the risks of giving a live rodent to a pet snake for dinner is the possibility that the snake will wind up getting bitten. Rodent bites range from small and superficial to severe, deep punctures. These bites can damage the snake’s eyes, tongue, mouth, and even internal organs and spine. They also have the potential to introduce harmful bacteria into the snake’s system.
>
> “Superficial wounds are treated with supportive measures, antibiotics, and pain medications. However, deep wounds may require surgery to correct and can even lead to the death of the snake,” says Dr. Keller.

https://vetmed.illinois.edu/pet-health-columns/pet-snakes-diet-dead-alive/

Do mice sometimes kill the snakes they are fed to?

Comment: I owned a corn snake, which is mildly venomous, and it got a serious infection from a mouse bite...it was ignoring the mouse because it wasn't hungry at the time, just like in the example cited above.  So I don't have anything more than anecdotal evidence, but I'd call it at least plausible.